# No ID3 tag found with id3ren

Tags: mp3, id3

I am using the following command to rename my mp3 files:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 id3ren -template='%a/%t/%n %s.mp3' -notagprompt
```

It worked fine, but now I am getting the following error on some files:

> *** No ID3 tag found in ./bar.mp3

But on the Audio tab with the Properties of the file in Nautilus I do see the proper tags (as you can see in the image).

[image: Properties of bar.mp3]

Are these tags corrupt? 
If so, has anyone got a clue how I can fix the tags? 
Or are there other tools that are more robust (since Nautilus can read the tags and id3ren can't)?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. The ID3 tag has to be converted from ID3v2 to ID3v1 before `id3ren` can read it. The simple utility `id3convert` can do the trick. Either of these commands will perform the same action, converting any ID3 tag to ID3v1:

```
id3convert -1 *.mp3
id3convert --v1tag *.mp3
```